# Append rows to a dataframe with purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I have a task that requires many api calls by week. I would like to append all of this data together with concise code via `purrr`, but I am having difficulty making `Sys.sleep` work in my function.

Below is some fake data. I am pretending this is the API backend:

```
#call 1
week1 <- as_tibble(list(week = rep(1,7),value = rnorm(7,0,1)))

#call 2
week2 <- as_tibble(list(week = rep(2,7),value = rnorm(7,0,1)))

#call 3
week3 <- as_tibble(list(week = rep(3,7),value = rnorm(7,0,1)))

#append
pretend_full_api_data <- bind_rows(week1, week2, week3)
```

This function works

```
by_api_call <- function(weeknumber){
  weeki <- pretend_full_api_data %>%
    filter(week == weeknumber)
}

seq(from = 1, to = 3) %>% 
map_df(~by_api_call(.))
```

The problem is that APIs often require a sleep time. So I tried to modify as follows:

```
by_api_call <- function(weeknumber){
  weeki <- pretend_full_api_data %>%
    filter(week == weeknumber)
    Sys.sleep(2) #required sleep for API calls
}

seq(from = 1, to = 3) %>% 
map_df(~by_api_call(.))
```

The above code returns `0 rows`. What is the problem with the above function?

Comment: You need to return `weeki` after `Sys.sleep(2)`. Besides I wonder how much `Sys.sleep(2)` will help here as that indicates your API call is asynchronous in nature which is not very common in r.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not working because the function `by_api_call` is not returning nothing. You need to add the function `return` to actually retrieve something from your function.

If you need to see the a technical discussion see the book [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#return-values) by Hadley Wickham (Most Valuable Player in R language).

Your code needs this tuning, to actually do the desired work

```
# API stuff..

# this is the function that actually works...

by_api_call <- function(weeknumber){
  weeki <- pretend_full_api_data %>%
    filter(week == weeknumber)
    Sys.sleep(2) #required sleep for API calls

  return(weeki) # return is your friend...
}

# calling the API function
week_numbers <- seq(from = 1, to = 3, by = 1)

(map_df(week_numbers, by_api_call))
```

---